# How to make two way WITH RECURSIVE query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to go *both up and down* in hierarchical rows using WITH RECURSIVE in postgres 13 ?

I have two table :

- **study** : id, title
- **affiliation** study_id(fk), affiliated_id(fk) ( the parent )

I got only working query to go 'downward' :

```
WITH RECURSIVE study_affiliation AS (
SELECT S.id, A.affiliated_id, S.title FROM study S LEFT JOIN affiliation A ON A.study_id = S.id WHERE S.id = 2
UNION
SELECT S.id, A.affiliated_id, S.title FROM study S INNER JOIN affiliation A ON A.study_id = S.id INNER JOIN study_affiliation SA ON A.affiliated_id = SA.id
)
SELECT * FROM study_affiliation
```

To reproduce :

```
CREATE TABLE study (
    id  int,
    title varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE affiliation (
    id int,
    study_id int,
    affiliated_id int
)
INSERT INTO study VALUES (1, 'study 1');
INSERT INTO study VALUES (2, 'study 2');
INSERT INTO study VALUES (3, 'study 3');

INSERT INTO affiliation VALUES (1, 2, 1 );
INSERT INTO affiliation VALUES (2, 3, 2);
```

I would like to go both ways recursively to get both parent study1 and child study3, but with my query it's only downward :

```
2   1   study 2
3   2   study 3
```

Comment: You need to specify the condition of the upwards move. Please provide more details of what you want to achieve, and also post sample data and desired output. A side note: you do not need to join `study` at every step, because you keep `study_id` along all the tree. So you can join it to the result of the recursive subquery.

Comment: I edited to add tables to reproduce @astentx

Comment: I see: you need to return rows for parent alongside the data for children?

Comment: Yes, i could do it in two queries, ( up then down ) but if possible i would rather do it in one.

Answer (score 0):

You may start the hierarchy from the parent and then use your table with hierarchy to build other rows:

> ```
> with recursive a (id, parent_id) as (
>   select id, null::numeric
>   from study
>   where not exists (
>     select 'Get pure parents, i.e. that do not exist as child of any'
>     from affiliation filt
>     where filt.study_id = study.id
>   )
>   
>   union all
>   
>   /*Then add all the children to them*/
>   select aff.study_id, aff.affiliated_id
>   from a
>     join affiliation aff
>       on a.id = aff.affiliated_id
> )
>
> /*Retrieve all the names after the hierarchy was build*/
> select
>   a.*
>   , s.title
> from a
>   join study as s
>     on a.id = s.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | parent_id | title  
> -: | --------: | :------
>  1 |      null | study 1
>  2 |         1 | study 2
>  3 |         2 | study 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4ed5101ceb44637e2068e1302647db62)*